# Code of display node in linked list doesn't work

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I wrote code of insertion in linked list. But when I run this code, my display function doesn't work properly and print something else.

```
**ERROR IN CODE**
```

Here, I declare the head function as global variable and set it to NULL. After that when I return to main function and goes through it. after some code one node is assigned to structure p and the first node is declare as head (now our head is not NULL, it contains some value in node), then we called the display function.
Now when we return to the display function and run it, it shows that our head is NULL and not NULL both.

**BELOW IS MY CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
struct node* head = NULL, * tail = NULL;

void printList()
{
    struct node* ptr = head;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty list\n");
    }
    printf("Nodes of the list are: \n");
    while (ptr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d \t", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

struct node* insertion(struct node** head, struct node** tail, int ele, int pos)
{
    int i;
    struct node* new_node, * temp;
    new_node = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf(" Dynamic memory allocation failed. Insertion can not be done");
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        new_node->data = ele;
        if (pos < 1)
        {
            printf(" Inappropriate position");
            return NULL;
        }
        else if (*head == NULL)
        {
            new_node->next = NULL;
            *head = *tail = new_node;
            return (new_node);
        }
        else if (pos == 1)
        {
            new_node->next = *head;
            *head = new_node;
            return(new_node);
        }
        else
        {
            temp = *head;
            i = 1;
            while (i < pos - 1 && temp != NULL)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
                i++;
            }
            if ((temp == NULL) || ((i == pos - 1) && (temp->next == NULL)))
            {
                new_node->next = NULL;
                (*tail)->next = new_node;
                (*tail) = new_node;
                return (new_node);
            }
            else
            {
                new_node->next = temp->next;
                temp->next = new_node;
                return (new_node);
            }
        }
    }

}


int main()
{
    struct node* head, * tail, * p;
    int n, i, ele, pos;

    do {
        printf(" Enter the number of elements initially in linked list:   ");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if (n < 0)
        {
            printf(" Enter the number greater than zero \n");
        }
    } while (n < 0);
    printf(" Enter the elements of linked list \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("%d element : ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &p->data);
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = p;
            tail = p;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = p;
            tail = p;
        }
    }

    printList();

    printf(" Enter the value which you want to insert:  ");
    scanf("%d", &ele);

    printf(" Enter the position at which you want to insert:  ");
    scanf("%d", &pos);

    insertion(&head, &tail, ele, pos);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Share the *actual* output, not "something like..." that's not real output.

Comment: There are many issues. It's time to start learning how to use your debugger. This is time well invested and it will quickly pay off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    struct node* head, * tail, * p;
```

This is your problem. You're declaring local variables in main named `head` and `tail` that hide the globals while in that scope.  When you assign to head and tail later in main, you're changing the value of the locals. The globals remain unchanged.

Comment: I deleted it but it doesn't show anything yet

Comment: What output are you getting and what output are you expecting? When I replaced line with `struct node *p;`, it prompts for the length of the list, the value of each element, and then prints the list.  (It doesn't print the list *after* the final insertion, but that's because you don't call printList again.)  As an aside, you never free your memory.

Comment: **OUTPUT **        -> stands for new line in this comment                 -> Enter the number of elements initially in linked list:    4         -> Enter the elements of linked list       -> 1 element :   2     ->  2 element :       4      -> 3 element :     5        -> 4 element :           7           -> Empty list        -> Nodes of the list are:         -> Enter the value which you want to insert:       and so on.            I ask in question that  why Empty list is printed when my head is not NULL

Comment: I'm not sure what to say, then. If you replace `struct node* head, * tail, * p;` with `struct node *p;` in the first line of main, it should print `Nodes of this list are: -> 2 4 5 7`. Did you forget to recompile?